The union of two geodesics is still a geodesic
Let $M$ be a geodesic complete manifold, and $p_1, p_2, p_3\in M$. Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:\mathbb{R}\to M$ be two geodesics on $M$, such that $\gamma_1(0)=p_1,\gamma_1(a)=p_2=\gamma_2(0)$ and $\gamma_2(b)=p_3$. If I know that the curve $\tilde\gamma:[0,a+b]\to M$ defined on $[0,a]$ as $\gamma_1$ and $[b,a+b]$ as $\gamma_2$ is still a geodesic from $p_1$ to $p_3$, then can I conclude that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ coninside on $[0,a+b]$(up to some reparametrization)? Especially, I want to show that $\tilde\gamma(a+b)=\gamma_1(a+b)$.
This problem comes from http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/24S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec15.pdf, in page 2 to page 3, the end of proof for second part of Hopf-Rinow theorem. I don't know why the author says "obviously $\tilde\gamma$ has to coincide with $\gamma$".

Why must $\gamma_1'(a)=\gamma_2'(0)$?

I didn't say $\gamma_1'(a)=\gamma_2'(0)$. If this holds, then the answer follows directly from uniqueness of geodesic with given initial point and speed

I understand. So I'm suggesting you prove that statement. At least you should immediately see an intuitive argument. I think the statement of the problem would be clearer if you supposed that the union of the two geodesics is still distance-minimizing.

If $\gamma_1'(a)\ne\gamma_2'(0)$, then in a enough small geodesic ball at $\gamma_1(a)$, I can find two points $q,q'\in\exp_{\gamma_1(a)}(\partial\overline{B(0,\epsilon)})=:A$, which are intersection points of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ with $A$, and then by triangle inequality, the distance $d(q_1,q_2)$ is smaller then $L(\tilde\gamma\cap A)$, contradicts to the minimial length of $\tilde\gamma$. This is intuitive from plane geometry, but is it in general riemmanian manifold feasible?

Maybe work in a geodesic normal coordinate ball centered at the point?

You already know that there is a unique geodesic passing through a given point with a given velocity at that point. For any $t_1 \in (0,a)$, both $\tilde\gamma$ and $\gamma_1$ pass through $\gamma_1(t_1)$ with the same velocity, since they are identical on a neighborhood of $t_1$. So what does that say about the geodesics $\tilde\gamma$ and $\gamma_1$? Similarly for $\tilde\gamma$ and $\gamma_2$ at $\gamma_2(t_2)$ for any $t_2 \in (0,b)$.
